# Windows Phone 8.1 Load Sound Issue with StreamResourceInfo

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am converting an app from WP7 to WP8.1 The codes for WP7 no longer works for WP8.1

> ```
>         sfxLeft = new MediaElement();
>         sfxRight = new MediaElement();
> ```

```
        StreamResourceInfo streamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(wav, UriKind.Relative));

        var sfx = SoundEffect.FromStream(streamInfo.Stream);

        sfxLeft = sfx.CreateInstance();
        sfxRight = sfx.CreateInstance();
```

StreamResourceInfo does not exists for WP8.1 anymore. Anyone know how I can re-write this line to make it work for WP8.1?

**Updated Code.**

Here's the new code below, but now it seems the sfxLeft and sfxRight are always NULL. I thought the below code would set sfxLeft and sfxRight, but it's still NULL.

```
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        test();

    }

    async private Task test()
    {
        Uri wav = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/eye_poke.wav", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(wav);

        stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();

        sfxLeft = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream).CreateInstance();
        sfxRight = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream).CreateInstance();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To play sound using XNA Framework in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight App

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(wav);
Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
SoundEffect Sound1 = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
Sound1.Play();
```

Or you can use MediaElement for both RT and Silverlight but they are in different namespace,

```
MediaElement mediaElement1 = new MediaElement();
mediaElement1.Source = wav
mediaElement1.AutoPlay = false;
rootGrid.Children.Add(mediaElement1)
```

Comment: It didn't work.I'm using WP 8.1 (universal app)Sytax seems to be off

Comment: Are you able to build the project successfully?? As far i know SoundEffect is the part of XNA framework and you can't use XNA media library in Universal App (win phone 8.1)

Comment: @amarankes Edited my answer.Check if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I figured it out by using the media element in XAML and then add codes in c# to play it.

Comment: you can not use two media elements on same page at a time.